# Are we ready to answer Drupal 8 questions (now)?

Tags: discussion

Question from 9 months ago: [Are we ready to answer Drupal 8 questions?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2192/are-we-ready-to-answer-drupal-8-questions)

Since

1. Significant time has passed, and related to that
2. Drupal 8's codebase is now much less volatile

I suggest we revisit this topic.

I say we are, if nothing else, based on the fact that (at least) two high profile members have themselves asked questions:

kiamlaluno: [How do I alter the route defined by another module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81362/how-do-i-alter-the-route-defined-by-another-module)

letharion (me): [How do I implement routes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80713/how-to-implement-routes-in-drupal-8)

I'm about to ask another question, but I'm willing to accept that it will be closed if it turns out that we still say no. Then we ought to close the above two question as well though.

Comment: Less volatile?  I just imploded a site today...  :)

Comment: So did I >_< Hence my question on the main site. But I do think it's become less volatile than it was. :)

Comment: @MPD I don't know why, but I read _employed_ instead of _imploded_. `:)`

Comment: @MPD Concur - I just annihilated a D8 site by trying to get Views to pick up some custom entities. This should be fun :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think we are ready, even though there are things that still needs to be fixed in Drupal 8.
As my question shows, there are things that were possible in Drupal 7 that are not still possible in Drupal 8. That doesn't mean a question about Drupal 8 should not be asked, even if a definitive answer could be given only months after the question is asked.

I would avoid asking questions about which modules to use in Drupal 8, especially when the question is about third-party modules, but I think we are ready for programming questions.

Comment: Just commenting to echo this.  Let's get the [tag:8] tag out of it's box for good :)

Comment: +1. I'm subscribed to the 8 tag and will try to answer interesting 8.x questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we are ready.

Since some issues people are facing may not be the best fit for Q/A, I went ahead and made a chat room:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10167/drupal-8-answers

Ideally, we want good, answerable questions, but this can serve as a place for less concrete problems.

Comment: The chat room is a good idea, but more people in the know are likely to frequent one of the [Drupal IRC](https://drupal.org/irc) channels. Just so people know there are options to get D8 help that's not suitable for this site :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do we want Drupal 8 to be ready? Can we help the process? 
Let's empower module developers to upgrade their modules!

From my point of view, this is the current focus. 
To help Drupal 8 get shipped with a good set of modules.

Helping this process to happen will also provide more feedback to the core team and more issues which need treatment and may bring Drupal 8 launch closer...

I suggest we not only add "8" label but any other related labels as well. symphony and twig are already there. Can you think of more?

Comment: It's not that I disagree, but what exactly are you suggesting?

Comment: Thanks Letharion for your clarifying question. I was only suggesting that stackexchange is a good place for those of use who know Drupal 8 to help others join the ride. But if you are asking, I suggest we open some more labels related to that. symphony and twig are already there. Can you think of more?

Comment: @Druvision We don't need to create those tags they'll just happen naturally when a question comes in. Twig's already there because of [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80713/how-to-implement-routes-in-drupal-8), and there are a bunch of symfony questions too. Letharion also posted another [D8 learning question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80713/how-to-implement-routes-in-drupal-8) which is awesome, if you're comfortable with any 'section' of the D8 API yourself and can post one of these self-answered tutorial-ish questions it would be very well received!

Comment: Right, tags are not created beforehand. In fact, there isn't a page that allows to create tags; tag synonyms are created from a page, but that is a different thing.